# Laravel 5 - Change all values in a Column of a table

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have a table with column called "estado" and I want change all the column in one shot.

This is the right method? The faster one?

```
$vendedor = Vendedor::with('produtos')->find( $idVendedor );

    foreach ( $vendedor->produtos as $produto ) {
        $produto->pivot->estado = $novoEstado;
    };
```

The column what I want change is "estado". There's a way to do it without the foreach?

Comment: why javascript ans jquery in tags?

Comment: i suggest you do it database side.

Comment: Why do it at database side?

Answer (score 1):

**Update Specific column you want to upadate using Laravel eloquent.**

Way -> 1

[Status-> Column you want to update]

```
Model::where('status', '=', 1)->update(['status' => 0]);
```

Way -> 2

[Status-> Column you want to update]

```
$allData = Model::where('status', 1)->get();
                foreach ($allData as $data){
                    $data->status = 0;
                    $data->update();
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest would be to just use the query builder for this (instead of your model)

```
DB::table('table_name')->where('vendedor_id', $idVendedor)->update('estado', $novoEstado);
```

Comment: Tnx dude. I discover that after some research, but tnx anyway.

By the way, there's a method getting the table and using ->save() ?